# Content-editable div with auto expendable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a div with contenteditable=true. It is autoexpandable like this: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

But what I need is the expansion should be revers side means, if I press enter key the div should expand to **the upper side not to downward side**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that, because the html document expands from left to right and from top to bottom, what you can do is to scroll down when creating a new line ... this will create the illusion that the div expands upwards.

Try adding this in the function:

```
window.scrollBy(0,fontHeight);
```

Or this using jQuery:

```
$('div[contenteditable=true]').animate({
scrollTop: '+=xx' //xx= fontHeight
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You can see it in facebook's comment box in image lightbox.